# Salesforce API: Instance_url from oauth2 access_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, salesforce, oauth-2.0

I authenticating salesforce app using Oauth2. But I am not getting instance_url in access_token.

my code for authenticating is

```
   access_token = oauth_client.web_server.get_access_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => oauth_redirect_uri, :grant_type => 'authorization_code')
```

and when I do

```
    instance_url = access_token["instance_url"]
```

I get

```
  undefined method `[]' for #<OAuth2::AccessToken:0x10113f7e8>
```

Help!

Comment: I could be way off base here, but looking here (http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/05/31/telesales-rails-heroku/), could it be you need `sfdc_instance_url`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the version of the oauth2 gem that you are using.